# Problems with popup using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, django

I don't have any ideas why popup don't take 2 arguments  `(id_get_post_status2 and id_popup_title2)`.

This is my Code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#popup5").hide();
    PopUpHide5();
});
function PopUpShow5(main_id, id, description, data_date, end_date, priority, status, title){
    $("#popup5").show();
    $(document).keyup(function(ev){
    if(ev.keyCode == 27)
        window.location = '/';
    });
    document.getElementById("id_get_post_pk2").value = main_id;
    document.getElementById("id_get_post_id2").value = id;
    document.getElementById("id_get_post_description2").value = description;
    document.getElementById("id_get_post_start_date2").value = data_date;
    document.getElementById("id_get_post_end_date2").value = end_date;
    document.getElementById("id_get_post_priority2").value = priority;
    document.getElementById("id_get_post_status2").value = status;
    document.getElementById("id_popup_title2").innerHTML = popup_title;

}
function PopUpHide5(){
    $("#popup5").hide();
}
```

HTML popup:

```
<div class="b-popup" id="popup5" >
    <div class="b-popup-content">
        <div style="width:100%;  height:10%;">
            <center><b><font color=#000000 size="5" "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif><p id="id_popup_title2"></p></font></b></center>
        </div>
            <form action="" method="post" >{% csrf_token %}
            <font color=#000000 size="3"> 

                <input id="id_get_post_pk2" value="" type="hidden" maxlength="9999" name="get_post_pk" type="text">
                <input id="id_get_post_id2" type="hidden" name="get_post_id" type="text" >
                <input id="id_post_request2" value="3" type="hidden" maxlength="1" name="post_request" type="text">
                <input id="id_get_post_status2" value="" type="hidden" name="status_post" type="text" >
                <div style="width:100%;  height:55%;">
                <label for="id_description_post" style=" display:table; margin-top:0px; padding-left:13px;">Description :<br></label><textarea id="id_get_post_description2" maxlength="9999" name="description_post" style="resize:none; font-size: 12pt; width:100%;  height:90%;" autofocus onkeyup="enableField(this.form,this.value)" type="text"></textarea><br>
                </div>
                <div style="width:100%;  height:6%;">
                <label for="id_start_date" style=" display:table; text-align: center;">Start date : </lable><input type="text" name="start_date" id="datetimepicker18" style="width:26%;  height:120%;" readonly/>  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;              
                <label>End date : </label><input type="text" name="end_date" id="datetimepicker19" style="width:26%;  height:120%;" readonly/>  
                </div>
                <div style="width:100%;  height:10%;">
                <p align="left" style="padding-left:23px;"><label>Priority : </label>
                <select method="post" name="priority_post">
                       <option value="1" id="id_priority_post2" name="priority_post" >High</option>
                   <option value="2" id="id_priority_post2" name="priority_post" >Medium</option>
                   <option value="3" id="id_priority_post2" name="priority_post" selected="selected">Low</option>
                </select></p>
                </div>
                <div style="width:100%;  height:23%;">
                <center><input type="submit" name="bttnsubmit" value="Apply" ONCLICK="window.location.href='/'" style="height:30px; width:80px;" >&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <input type="button" value="Cancel" ONCLICK="window.location.href='/'" style="height:30px; width:80px" ></center>
                </div>
            </font>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

And how i called popup :

```
<div style="width:5%; float:right;">
        <div id="b-container">
                <div class="photo" data-title="Edit"><a href="javascript:PopUpShow5({{ item.main_id }}, {{ item.id }}, &quot;{{ item.description }}&quot;, &quot;{{ item.data_date|date:'Y-m-d H:i' }}&quot;, &quot;{{ item.end_date|date:'Y-m-d H:i' }}&quot;, {{ item.priority }}, {{ item.status }}, &quot;Edit item&quot;)"><input type="image" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}images/edit.png" border="0" width="17" height="17" </a></div>
                </div>          
                  </div>
```

P.S. Other variables post to django correctly...

Comment: your image tag is not closed. <input type="image" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}images/edit.png" border="0" width="17" height="17" />

Comment: Thanks) i'm corrected code, but this don't resolve my problem

Comment: Please correct the code here too. Also, I am not sure what you are expecting this to do: <form action="" method="post" >{% csrf_token %}
            <font color=#000000 size="3">. Html renders '{% csrf_token %} as text. http://jsfiddle.net/4EafL/

Comment: Also, you have a ton of tags that are not right. You need to make sure all of your tags are closed. I daresay that you have more tags left open than ones that are properly closed.